# Как сделать сдвиг влево и вывести каждые 2 цифры через пробел (Python)

Tags: python

Нужно сделать так что бы конечное содержимое переменной  `crypt = 536342316124`  сдвинулось на 1 позицию , что бы получилось так `363423161245`. И в конце это число разделилось на пары = `36 34 23 16 12 45` 
За оформление не серчайте обращаюсь первый раз.

```
text = "привет"

keys = {
'а':'11', 'б':'21', 'в':'31', 'г':'41', 'д':'51','е':'61',
'ё':'12', 'ж':'22', 'з':'32', 'и':'42', 'й':'52', 'к':'62',
'л':'13', 'м':'23', 'н':'33', 'о':'43', 'п':'53', 'р':'63',
'с':'14', 'т':'24', 'у':'34', 'ф':'44', 'х':'54', 'ц':'64',
'ч':'15', 'ш':'25', 'щ':'35', 'ъ':'45', 'ы':'55', 'ь':'65',
'э':'16', 'ю':'26', 'я':'36', ' ':'46', '.':'56', ',':'66'}

# Шифрование
crypt = ""
for i in text:
    if i in keys:
        crypt += keys[i]
        crypt += " "
    print(crypt)

# Расшифрование
temp = ""
decrypt = ""
for i in crypt:
if i != " ":
    temp += i
else:
    for j in keys:
        if keys[j] == temp:
            decrypt += j
    temp = ""
print(decrypt)

# Шифрование
crypt = ""
for i in text:
if i in keys:
    crypt += keys[i]
        crypt += ""
    print(crypt)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сдвиг влево

```
crypt = crypt[1:] + crypt[:1]
```

Разделение на пары:

```
t = list(map(''.join, zip(crypt[::2], crypt[1::2])))
crypt = ' '.join(t)
```

Comment: Сдвиг получился удачно. Но разделение на пары выдает какой-то странный результат:
  `<map object at 0x000001ED3CB0B710>`

Comment: **<map object at 0x000001ED3CB0B710>**

Comment: Теперь выводит : **['36', '34', '23', '16', '12', '45']** А можно ли сделать так что бы эти числа были в строке `crypt` ? т.е что бы при выводе ее было **36 34 23 16 12 45** 
Что бы  можно было применить `#Расшифрование`

Comment: Спасибо большое ! Очень сильно выручили !